# ArcGIS Online Image Offset

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, arcgis-pro, 3d-model

I have three geo-referenced images of a museum layout that I have been able to offset by "x" number of meters in ArcScene and ArcGIS Pro. I want to publish the three images online and have it look like below: [image: 3D images]

I am not able to find a way to add offset to the layers in ArcGIS Online Scenes. I have tried to exported directly to a [Exporting ArcScene Documents to 3D Web Scenes](http://support.esri.com/white-paper/2018) and viewed in Esri CityEngine Web Viewer. However the image quality is very low and transparent image backgrounds are not allowed. [image: ESRI CityEngine View]

Unfortunately this does not allow for easy navigation and will not work for us. I want to do this in ArcGIS Online if possible but I am open to other solutions that would allow other GIS features to be added to the images.

Comment: R can do this easy with anglr package, it just wraps raster data to convert to mesh3d and vis in rgl

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @KHibma](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223263/arcgis-online-image-offset#comment344603_223263):

> You might be able to create a Scene Layer Package (SLP) and publish
>   it. I think you'll need to bake the "offset" (z) into the layers to
>   get this work. (I say 'think' as I dont have much experience with
>   this). Some ideas here including the SLP:
>   https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2017/01/03/72321/